# Printing section numbers using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a function `void numbers(ostream& outs, const string& prefix, unsigned int levels);` that prints output to the ostream outs.

The output consists of the string prefix followed by "section numbers" of the form 1.1., 1.2., 1.3., and so on. The levels argument determines how may levels the section numbers have. For example, if levels is 2, then the section numbers have the form x.y. If levels is 3, then section numbers have the form x.y.z. The digits permitted in each level are always '1' through '9'. As an example, if prefix is the string "THERBLIG" and levels is 2, then the function would start by printing:

> THERBLIG1.1.
>
> THERBLIG1.2.
>
> THERBLIG1.3.
>
> and end by printing:
>
> THERBLIG9.7.
>
> THERBLIG9.8.
>
> THERBLIG9.9.

The stopping case occurs when levels reaches zero (in which case the prefix is printed once by itself followed by nothing else).

My current code correctly prints out all the sections when level is 2, but when level is 3 it does not. How do I make my code more dynamic and universal so that it can take in any number as levels? (When levels is 3, the output should be 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3....1.2.1..).

Here's my code:

```
void numbers(ostream& outs, const string& prefix, unsigned int levels){
    if (levels > 1){

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
            for (int k = 1; k <= 9; k++){
                string s = prefix + char('0' + i);
                s  += '.';
                s += char('0' + k);
                s  += '.';
                outs<<s<<endl;
            }

        }
        numbers(outs, prefix, levels - 1);
    }

    else{
        levels = 0;
        if (levels == 0){
            cout<<prefix<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't appear to be working for a single level, either - I get the singular output "P", which I suppose for this example is intended.

Comment: @CalmBit Yes, it only works for 2 levels. I'm trying to make it more dynamic so that it works for every layer

Comment: If `levels` is `2`, as in your example, then your loop(s) ends up doing 81 iterations.  If `levels` is 3, how many iterations do you do?  And when `levels` is 4?  What about for the general case `levels` is `n`?  Try not to think about the nested loop structure and just think about how many iterations your code needs to do.

Comment: @dmcdougall I just don't understand how I can track each x.y.z value. For example, what tracks and makes 1.1.9 change to 1.2.1 afterwards?

Comment: Think about that in a minute.  First figure out how many iterations you need to do.

Comment: @dmcdougall Don't I need to do 9 iterations? Since it's 1.1, 1.2, 1.3...1.9?

Comment: Nope.  When `levels` is 1 you'll do nine iterations.  What about when `levels` is 2?  When I say 'iterations' I mean the __total__ number of iterations to generate the output.

Comment: @dmcdougall Well for each level it's different. Since each level is 9, we'd have 9^levels correct?

Comment: Yep.  So, without the recursion, what you could do is have a single loop over all 9^levels iterations, and check when you reach a multiple of nine to increment the next level.  Your question about how to track the position is a good one.  One approach might be to store each of the levels in an integer array of length `levels`.  Make sense?

Comment: @dmcdougall Yes it does. We could create an array of size[levels] and with each 9th iteration we could increment or decrement depending on where we are at

Comment: It looks like you've already accepted an answer, and one that's recursive.  You might consider exploring this design too to understand a different approach to solving the problem.  Hope this helped.

Comment: @dmcdougall Yes, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion using backtracking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void numbers(ostream& outs, const string& prefix, unsigned int levels){

    if (levels == 0) {
        outs << prefix << endl;
        return;
    }

   for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        string dot = (levels == 1 ? "" : "."); //handle the case the lowest level
        string s = prefix +  std::to_string(i) + dot;
        numbers(outs, s, levels - 1);
   }
}

int main() {
    int level = 3;
    numbers(cout, "", level);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `auto dot`?

Comment: A variable of automatically deduced type called `dot`

Comment: @sbooth My compiler is having trouble understanding it. It is saying "auto changes meaning in c++11; please remove it"

Comment: auto is a new keyword in C++11. In this case, it automatically determines type of dot basing on type of right hand side. For the case, it equal to string dot :)

Comment: your need to specify -std=c++11 to your compile flag. I edited for lower version of C++.
Anyway, for your job, you can use BACKTRACKING method (like I did).

Comment: @khôinguyễn Thank you a lot for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void numbers(string& outs, const string& prefix, unsigned int levels){
    if (levels >= 1){
        for (int k = 1; k <= 9; k++){
            string tmpOut = outs + char('0' + k) + ".";
            numbers(tmpOut, prefix, levels - 1);
        }
    }
    else{
        outs.erase(outs.size() - 1, 1);
        cout<<prefix<< outs << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
   string out;
   numbers(out, "prefex ", 2);
   numbers(out, "prefex ", 3);
   return 0;
}
```

later I will describe it